# Open source project - framework or core PHP?

Tags: php, open-source

I am working in some open source project in PHP.
My question is, should I make it using some kind of framework, say Laravel, or in plain PHP, in a hope for a large no of programmers using it? Btw, eventually, I do need to setup the routing, filtering, views for my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The  things that you should ask yourself are:**

- What kind of open source project it is? It is a blog platform, it is
  a api for dogs name, a package that will give some functionality to
  others?
- The number of programmers using it depends in the number of
  programmers feeling attracted to contribute to the project, the
  number of devs that need the project, the new functionality over
  existing projects (almost always there is something quite the same
  that already exist).

**Identify**

- What you wanna to build, it will be simple, it will need a framework
  like laravel or a more light one like lumen?
- The integrations and interactions that your project will have.
- The kind of people that will affect (not only programmers).

*More requirements...*

**Example**

If you wanna make a CMS in laravel you will notice that October is a popular project, so what difference your project from others? Is it just something that you can make contributing to the October project?

Is it something like a intelligent CMS using machine learning that suggest the perfect content for topics?

**Personal recommendation:**

For the sake of learning if you already know php , I recommend you a framework, (if you are not the type of person that doesn't have curiosity of how things works, you'll learn a lot).

Better php, easier to implement, niche focus.

PD: Don't make a open source project just because you wanna to be popular, make it for fun, for learning, for helping, for resolve a problem, but for the sake of god , don't make it for the glamorous shines and stars and the ego bump of github fork.

Why? What happen if it doesn't reach the number of programmers you wanna to reach? ***Will you just abandoned it?***

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Your last line says all. Will use laravel now. Its actually an enjoyable experience always. Was working on a data entry solution to an existing database. Will check out Octobercms though.

Comment: @Praveen random off-topic comment: I'm a girl :P, glad you find it useful.We often found ourselves trying to find the perfect global solution for all problems (the sad and fun thing) is that every project has their own requirements and the requirements will tell what you need if you close enough.
I think Open Source code is really a beautiful experience, but some times you need to find the proper driven

Comment: Oh I am sorry. Thank you so much once again. It gave a good motivation and I am on my way. :)

Answer (score -1):

I am currently enrolled in a course on web development. The professor told us that the industry standard is to use a php framework. We are using CodeIgniter which is pretty simple to learn / use and has a rather active community.